# Reverse boolean return of function in Ramda

Tags: javascript, typescript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I've just started exploring Ramda library and fall into some problem.

Let's say we have a function, that takes string and list of strings as arguments and returns true if given string is in the list. At line 4 I want to log first element from `otherList` that is **not** included in `list`.

```
const isInList = R.curry((name: string, list: string[]) => list.some(elem => elem === name))
const list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
const otherList = ['a', 'b', 'd', 'c']
console.log(otherList.find(!isInList(R.__, list)))
```

I can't find Ramda function that would reverse logical result of given function.

If it existed it would look like something like this:

```
const not = (func: (...args: any) => boolean) => (...args: any) => !func(args)
```

Then my goal could be archived like:

```
console.log(otherList.find(not(isInList(R.__, list)))
```

Does function like that exsist in Ramda?

Comment: Yes, as you found it's [`R.complement`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#complement).  The function [`R.not`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#not) is meant for something simpler: taking the logical *not* of a boolean (or really of any `false-y`/`truth-y` JS value.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`R.complement`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#complement) is the way to negate a function

```js
const isInList = R.includes;
const isNotInList = R.complement(isInList);

const list = ['Giuseppe', 'Francesco', 'Mario'];

console.log('does Giuseppe Exist?', isInList('Giuseppe', list));
console.log('does Giuseppe Not Exist?', isNotInList('Giuseppe', list));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js" integrity="sha256-xB25ljGZ7K2VXnq087unEnoVhvTosWWtqXB4tAtZmHU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Found it! It's called `R.complement()`

Answer (score 1):

Try R.difference():

```
const list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
const otherList = ['a', 'b', 'd', 'c']
R.difference(otherList, list); //=> ['d']
```

Online demo [here](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.26.1#?const%20list%20%3D%20%5B%27a%27%2C%20%27b%27%2C%20%27c%27%5D%0Aconst%20otherList%20%3D%20%5B%27a%27%2C%20%27b%27%2C%20%27d%27%2C%20%27c%27%5D%0AR.difference%28otherList%2C%20list%29)

Comment: Maybe it's not linked with my question, but it's super useful, thanks!